# How to set different zoom levels in layers in a map using leaflet.

Tags: javascript, dictionary, leaflet

How to set different zoom level in layers in a map.
I need to show  different zoom levels in different layers.
For example I have 2 layers 1.city, 2.state. When map initialization zoom level is 18, but when I am displaying STATE layer I have to set the zoom level into 22.

I am using the below code.

```
var city = new L.LayerGroup();
var state = new L.LayerGroup();

var cloudmadeUrl = 'http://{s}.tile.cloudmade.com/BC9A493B41014CAABB98F0471D759707/997/256/{z}/{x}/{y}.png',
  cloudmade = new L.TileLayer(cloudmadeUrl, {maxZoom: 18}),
  map = new L.Map('map', {layers: [cloudmade,city,state], center: new    L.LatLng(17.7003292, 82.01161768), zoom:18 });
```

How can I set zoom level at layer initialization?

Answer (score 5):

Here's a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mattias_jcb/3hkYh/) of an example of how to do this.

```
var map = new L.Map('amap', {
center: new L.LatLng(45.50144, -122.67599),
zoom: 4,
minZoom: 0,
maxZoom: 18,
layers: [
    L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.cloudmade.com/{key}/997/256/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
    maxZoom: 13,
    minZoom: 0,
    attribution: 'Map data &copy; 2011 OpenStreetMap contributors, Imagery &copy; 2011 CloudMade',
    key: 'BC9A493B41014CAABB98F0471D759707'
}),
    L.tileLayer('http://server.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/' + 'rest/services/World_Imagery/MapServer/tile/{z}/{y}/{x}', {
    minZoom: 14,
    maxZoom: 18,
    attribution: 'Tiles © Esri — ' 
        + 'Source: Esri, i-cubed, USDA, USGS, AEX, GeoEye, Getmapping, ' 
        + 'Aerogrid, IGN, IGP, UPR-EGP, and the GIS User Community'})
]});
```

Comment: This is the right way of achieving the desired behaviour, but unfortunately the rendering is not perfect when zooming in and out again, then the second layer is not removed properly. See [this open issue on github](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet/issues/1905).