# Leaflet - Switch GeoJSON based on zoom level

Tags: leaflet, geojson

I'd like to make a Leaflet map based on GeoJSON (not TileLayer) data, and have it switch between different GeoJSONs based on the zoom level. For example, switching from a state to county GeoJSON, or switching from a highly-simplified GeoJSON to a high resolution GeoJSON.

I see from this question [a How to set different zoom levels in layers in a map using leaflet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16370790/how-to-set-different-zoom-levels-in-layers-in-a-map-using-leaflet) that it can be done using the minZoom and maxZoom options when creating a TileLayer. However, these properties aren't available for a GeoJSON feature group. Is there a natural way to change maps based on zoom level when using GeoJSON?

Answer (score 2):

You can put a listener on map zoomend, removing one geojson (e.g. countries) and adding another one (e.g. counties) to the map.

Answer (score 1):

Check out [Adding/Removing Leaflet GeoJSON layers](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/41928/adding-removing-leaflet-geojson-layers). The answer there helped me pull off different GoeJSON sets at differing zoom levels.